# glTexSubImage2D deeply affects frame rate on gles 3.0

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures, opengl-es-3.0

I have a graphics engine which for every frame writes approximately 300 bytes of data
with approximately six `glTexSubImage2D` calls to a texture (including writing to mipmaps).
The texture is a texture of unigned bytes using `GL_RED` and `GL_R8` as format\internal format.
The uploading is performed via a pixel buffer, which in itself has been written to one frame ahead.

This quite small operation have a deep impact on the framerate regardless of what else gles is drawing.

Anyone have any idea of what is causing this frame rate drop, and how I can get past it?

*Update:*
Solidpixels answer indicates it's a synchronization issue. In this case, I would be perfectly fine even if the texture modification is not synchronized at all with the rendering. Can I just tell gles to just write the data straight into the texture memory without caring at all if just half the new data is there?

*Note:*
It is only the `glTexSubImage2D` which affects the frame rate, the `glSubBufferData` upload does not affect at all.
On some devices it seems to mather when I actually perform the `glTexSubImage2D` in respect to when I draw using the texture, not all devices though.

Comment: "can ...  just write the data straight into the texture memory without sync"? No method that I know of for textures, only buffers.

Comment: Yes, seems it's possible with texture buffers available in gles 3.2, or vulkan of course :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd guess on the devices which slow down you still have outstanding references to the texture in flight, so you are forcing the drivers to create a ghost allocation. In depth explanation here:

https://community.arm.com/graphics/b/blog/posts/mali-performance-6-efficiently-updating-dynamic-resources

Comment: Thanks for the link, I figured it was something with the pipeline.